# Solve the following congruence: 2x ≡ 7 (mod 17)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

**Question**
Solve the congruence 2x ≡ 7 (mod 17).

I have tried working out this problem but I am stuck midway. Could someone help me out by showing me or explaining how to proceed further?

Here is the work that I have so far:

Inverse of a modulo m is an integer b for which ab ≡ 1 (mod m),
a = 2
m = 17

17 = 8 ⋅ 2 + 1
2 = 2 ⋅ 1 + 0

The greatest common divisor is the last non-zero remainder values, that is, gcd (a, m) = 1.

Expressing the greatest commmon divisor as a multiple of a and m,
gcd (a, m) = 1
= 17 - 8 ⋅ 2
= 1 ⋅ 17 - 8 ⋅ 2

The inverse would then be the coefficient of a = 2, which in this case, would be -8.
And, since, -8 mod 17 = 9 , 9 is also the inverse of a modulo m.

Solving the congruence 2x ≡ 7 (mod 17) by multiplying each side by the inverse 9,
9⋅2x  ≡ 9⋅7 (mod 17)
18x ≡ 63 (mod 17)

And, this is the part where I am stuck. Could anyone help out? Thank you.

Comment: $18x \equiv x \pmod{17}$, and continue from your last line.

Comment: "17 = 8 ⋅ 2 + 1 2 = 2 ⋅ 1 + 0"  !!!!PLEASE!!!!! put in line breaks!  "seventeen equal eight times two plus twelve equals two times one plus zero"??????  I figure you *probably* mean $17=8\cdot 2 + 1$ and $2=2\times 1 +0$ but it's *really* hard to read.

Comment: You are done.  $18x \equiv 63\pmod {17}$ and $18x \equiv x\pmod {17}$ and so $x \equiv 63\pmod{17}$ is the solution.  You are done.  If you want to find a number between $0$ and $16$ you know $63 \equiv 12 \pmod {17}$ so $x \equiv 12 \pmod {17}$ is another way of expressing the same solution.  ... and to verify $2\times 12\equiv 24 \equiv 7\pmod {17}$  (also $2\times 63\equiv 126 \equiv 7*17 + 7\equiv 7\pmod {17}$.  So they are both the same solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$7+17=24=2 \times 12$, so $x \equiv 12 \pmod{17}$.

Answer (score 0):

you are basically done

$18x \equiv 63 \pmod{17}$ and $18x \equiv x \pmod {17}$ and $63\equiv 12 \pmod {17}$

so $x \equiv 12 \pmod{17}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$2x \equiv 7 \pmod {17}$$

$$9\times 2x \equiv 7\times 9 \pmod {17}$$

$$18x \equiv 63 \pmod {17}$$

$$18x \equiv x \equiv 63 \equiv 12 \pmod {17}$$

$63=3\times17+12$

$$x \equiv 12 \pmod {17}$$